# Accessing unicoded keys with spaces in them in Python 2.7

Tags: python, xlrd, dictionary, python-unicode

I am working on a project where I am trying to take Excel files (read in via `xlrd`) and geocode addresses in them.  For this, I am using a list of directories, with each directory entry a separate site.

Something like `addressList[0]` will result in the following:

```
{text:u'First name ': u'John',
 text:u'Site City': u'Indio',
 text:u'Site State': u'CA',
 text:u'Last name': u'Doe',
 text:u'Site Phone': u'760-555-1234',
 text:u'Site Zip': u'92201',
 text:u'Site Address1': u'1313 Mockingbird Lane',
 text:u'Site Name': u'Tyrell Industries',
 text:u'Hours': u'Mon-Fri 12:00-1:00',
 text:u'Affliation': u'Boys & Girls Clubs of America'}
```

(And I just realized in the spreadsheet, "affiliation" was spelled incorrectly. Meh.)

Now, I know from looking around that [keys in Python can have spaces in them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13474957/spaces-in-python-dictionary-keys), and that this shouldn't be a problem. But entering `addressList[0]['Site Phone']` results in a KeyError. In fact, trying to get the value of the 'Hours' key results in a similar KeyError.

Based on a [question on Unicode keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1254454/fastest-way-to-convert-a-dicts-keys-values-from-unicode-to-str), I tried the following:

```
STRING_DATA = dict([(str(k), v) for k, v in addressList[0].items()])
```

Which resulted in a dictionary with entries like:

```
"text:u'Site Name'": u'Tyrell Industries',
```

This is reasonably okay, except I'm now having to access the value via `STRING_DATA["text:u'Site Name'"]`, which seems like a pain.

Is there a quicker/easier way to use the keys?

Comment: I don't understand what that data structure is supposed to be. Where are those 'text' prefixes coming from? How are you receiving it, and how are you outputting it?

Comment: I get the data by opening the workbook using `xlrd.workbook_open`, then read in the data by creating a list and appending the dictionaries:

`addressList.append(dict(zip(column_names, siteSheet.row_values(rownum))))`

where `column_names` are obtained from the first row of the sheet. (The 'text:u' prefixes are added in automatically.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`text:u'First name ': u'John',` is not a valid `dict` entry.

the reason you have `text:` prefixs before keys like `text:u'First Name'` is, because you're using `xlrd cell`s as dict's keys.

you should explicitly extract values from cells by using `cell.value`

something like:

`new_keys = [k.value for k in addresslist[0]]`

Comment: Using `cell_value` when I read in the field names from the Excel file works well. Something like:  
  
`for i in range(NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS):
        column_names.append(site_sheet.cell_value(0, i))`  
  
gives me keys I can reference without a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

All you *should* need to get your column headings is this:

```
column_names = site_sheet.row_values(rowx=0, end_colx=NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)
```

However it appears the headings need a bit of a scrub e.g. `u'First name '` and `u'Last name'` could be made conform with other headings, by removing leading and trailing spaces and enforcing Title Case:

```
column_names = [x.strip().title()
    for x in site_sheet.row_values(row=0, end_colx=NUMBER_OF_COLUMNS)]
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm getting this from a third party source, so there's a bit of cleanup I know I can still do. But the main problem was doing something I probably shouldn't have been doing when values from the worksheet.